# Multiple reposts and closes

Tags: discussion, reposts

In cases like this [Reposted Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433868/how-to-create-a-tcp-client-to-send-commands-to-a-server-using-php) where the user has reposted the same question multiple times, is there anything automated that eventually shuts such a user down?

The user has posted the same question 4 times.

They get closed fairly fast, but I'm wondering if such a user eventually gets a ban, either via an automated process or a moderator saying 'enough is enough'.

Comment: Update: Gumbo has, thankfully, suspended the user after he posted his question six times.

Comment: Fantasitilicious

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clearly, this is a "flag: requires moderator attention" situation. Go to any of the posts and click the `flag` link at the bottom of the question. Describe what you see. They can decide how to handle it from there.

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot about that. Overall when I see something like this I am just baffled that someone didn't get the hint over the previous two closures complete with 'don't post duplicates' comments.

Answer (score 3):

It is mostly handled by the usual mechanisms. Most posters get the message fairly quickly. If they are unusually persistent (and this one might be), flag for moderator attention. They can insta-close, delete, lock, etc and summon the penalty box if necessary.